# Is there a command line tool to download Android emulator images (AVD Manager)?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to build a docker image with the Android emulator for testing purposes with Appium, and I've got all necessary except the avd images.
For now, when I run `android list avd` I have an empty list.

I have installed the following tools, but I missed some documentation about how to use them to retrieve images: `android update sdk -t tool,platform-tool,android-24,addon-google_apis-google-24,extra-google-webdriver`.

**Edit:** I'm working with `android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz`.

I've tried `android create avd -t android-24 -n android-24-avd` which said `Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.`, **but** `android-24` has no ABI

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-24"
     Name: Android 7.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 24
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:24"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 7.0 (API level 24)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `--components` option for `android update sdk`. For example

```
$ android update sdk --components=sys-img-x86-android-18
```

Comment: It's not working, I have an `Error: Flag '--components' is not valid for 'update sdk'.`. For information, I'm working with sdk 24.4.1 linux.